# Multiple fast readers single slow writer: is using shadow-data with atomic index safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm not sure I could squeeze the concept correctly in the title, but here's what I mean:

Suppose I have "slow", in the sense of really unfrequent, updates made to a data structure by a single thread, while there are multiple threads continuously reading the same data structure.

In the attempt to avoid locks, and being stuck on C++14 (so no std::shared_mutex available) and without boost, I thought to an approach where I keep 2 copies of the structure and use an atomic integer to index the current one.

Let's assume that the depth of 2 is enough and let's not worry about that, updates are so infrequent that there's enough time for a new version of the data structure to be "seen" by all the readers before a new update comes in.

Here's a snippet that shows a simplified version of what I was doing:

```
 /*
 * includes...
 */

struct datastructure_t {
    /*...*/
};


class StructSwapper
{
    std::atomic<unsigned int> current_index_;

    datastructure_t structures_[2];

public:
    StructSwapper (datastructure_t s)
        : current_index_(0)
        , structures_{std::move(s), {}}
    {}

    //Guaranteed to be called _infrequently_ by the same single thread
    void update (datastructure_t newdata)
    {
        auto const next_index = !current_index_.load();

        structures_[next_index] = std::move(newdata);

        current_index_.store(next_index);
    }


    //Called _frequently_ by multiple threads
    datastructure_t const & current_data() const
    {
        return structures_[current_index_.load()];
    }
};
```

So basically when the writer thread performs an update, it first modifies the "shadow" copy of the data structure, and then atomically updates the index the points to it.

Each reader thread will do something like:

```
void reader_thread(StructSwapper const &sw)
{
    auto const &current_data  = sw.current_data();


    if (current_data->find(...))                        //1
    {
        do_something (current_data->val1);              //2

        if (current_data->property2)                    //3
            do_something_else (current_data->val2);     //4
        /*...*/

    }
}
```

But then I started thinking: what guarantees that the compiler won't re-read the value of current_data in any of the lines marked 1,2,3,4 and then possibly get two different versions of it during the execution of this function if in the meantime an update was performed by the writer thread?

Maybe if the StructSwapper::current_data() is inline, it might have a look at it and see the use of the atomic variable as an index, but I doubt it would be enough anyway.

So, two questions:

1. Am I right thinking that this approach is not guaranteed to work as the compiler has no clue that the "snapshot" of the current_data has to really be taken only once?
2. I think it would probably make a difference if I instead returned an atomic reference to the current version of the data structure because in that case, the compiler would understand that it could get two different values out of two different reads, right?

EDIT: After seeing suggestions for optimizations related to a more relaxed memory ordering, I'd like to add I didn't report them in the above snippet, but they are indeed already in place in the real code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common approach and it works.

You need to make sure that no other thread is still reading the old data that your writer updates though. To solve that, readers often just make a copy of the data and use it as long as necessary.

> But then I started thinking: what guarantees that the compiler won't re-read the value of `current_data`.

The compiler may store the value of variable `current_data` on the stack and re-read it later, but it won't call `sw.current_data()` for you.

> Am I right thinking that this approach is not guaranteed to work as the compiler has no clue that the "snapshot" of the current_data has to really be taken only once?

That is incorrect.

> I think it would probably make a difference if I instead returned an atomic reference to the current version of the data structure because in that case, the compiler would understand that it could get two different values out of two different reads, right?

This is unnecessary.

---

A few optimizations:

```
void update (datastructure_t newdata)
{
    auto const next_index = !current_index_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); 
    structures_[next_index] = std::move(newdata);
    current_index_.store(next_index, std::memory_order_release); // (1) 
}


//Called _frequently_ by multiple threads
datastructure_t const & current_data() const
{
    return structures_[current_index_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)]; // Synchronises with (1).
}
```

Comment: Another option is to keep a reader lock count in each buffer, and the writer is blocked from writing the shadow buffer until all readers have moved from that (i.e are 2 writes old) to the last buffer. This depends on how quickly the readers do each read, and whether the writer can wait even that long.

Comment: @GemTaylor That would require each reader do extra atomic increment and decrement. Whereas with this mechanism each reader does one atomic load only.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, thanks but I'd like to convince myself that it is incorrect to assume that the compiler can call sw.current_data() multiple times, what's your reasoning behind your "it won't call sw.current_data() for you" statement? I'm thinking that no as-if rule would be violated, but I'd like to see a firm proof that I'm wrong. Maybe the compiler can't prove that the function doesn't have side effects and then cannot call it multiple times?.

Comment: @abigagli I am surprised by your thinking, C++ is an imperative language where things happen in the program order (with caveats for multithreading). What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Maxim, but I'm trading that lock for each reader does not have to quickly take a copy of the data, and there is still the small chance that taking the copy could take longer than 2 writers... Swings and Roundabouts... pay for copying or pay for an increment and a semaphore. I'm aware these are all problems previously solved, though using the unix pthread library may not be acceptable to all.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin because under the as-if rule, the compiler is allowed to do pretty much everything as long as the observable behavior is "as-if" the code was executed exactly as written in the source code. I'm just trying to justify theoretically why in this case it couldn't do such a thing. Since I'm not sure that the compiler can understand in this case that calling the function multiple times it would have altered the observable behavior, I'm wondering if there's a strict reasoning that can 100% made such compilation illegal

Comment: @abigagli The compiler may elide things when certain conditions are met, but generally it cannot do _pretty much everything_. It may never elide a call (it can inline it though), unless it is a call to a constructor of a copy that is being elided. And it may never turn one call into many calls.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin well, I don't completely agree, at least at a conceptual level. In theory, if the compiler can prove that a function is idempotent, it has enough ground to decide that it can call it 1 or 100 times without disturbing the observable state. If it stored the result of the first call in a register, but then some register pressure builds up, it might decide to reuse the register for something else without saving it on the stack and simply call again the function when its return value is required later in the code... (continues...)

Comment: ...  I know it's an unlikely scenario, but I wouldn't dismiss it as impossible. I'm still convinced that maybe this is not going to happen, but only because the compiler can't demonstrate certain property of the called function, not because in general it may "_never_ turn one call into many calls". All I'm saying is that sometimes it could. But if I'm wrong and you can refer me to where I can see that it is always prohibited to do so, I'll be glad to accept your answer

Comment: @abigagli I'm sorry, I have no interest in disproving your misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a second update while any reader is still working on the original data, you will have a data-race and thus Undefined Behavior.

So, infrequent is not enough, you need a guarantee that any two updates are far enough apart that the readers will all be working with the newest data before you get the second update.

That can be mitigated by having more positions available, by keeping track of how many readers are working with each copy and deferring updates, or by dynamically allocating as many copies as needed and managing them with shared-pointers. Whatever you do, take a critical look at whether it's correct and efficient enough.

Comment: yes I know that, the snippet is a very much simplified reduction, the real code has several other things that already take care of that, and since it was not the focus of my question, I didn't want to add too much "noise"...

Comment: Another option is to return a shared pointer to the readers, if the writer can invoke `new`.